# Android localStorage disappear after erasing the app from RAM

Tags: android, local-storage

I'm using Cordova.webView, and trying to use localStorage to cache user's username and password. However, though it is suggested that the localStorage is lasting, I find that every time I erase the app from the RAM, the localStorage goes away. So how to prevent this from happening?

By "erasing the app from RAM", I mean the action of killing the app's process from the background, e.g. in Android 4.0, holding the home button and click on the cross.

Comment: Save as soon as you update it.

Comment: What do you mean by save? @Simon

Answer (score 0):

On Android 4.4 and 5.0 
localStorage for my phonegap app persists even on restart. The only way I know to actually clear it is by clearing the app's cache, or uninstalling the app completely.

```
// Store
localStorage.lastname = "Smith";
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = localStorage.lastname;
```